# How to find path to vscode in Linux?

Tags: visual-studio-code, filezilla, pop-os

I'd like someone to help me with finding path to executable vscode in POP_!OS. I tried look in /usr/bin, i tried whereis code and which code, nothing worked and i'm still stuck. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Source of info:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

General Linux:
To find an executable file; Open a terminal, type `where NAME`, for the NAME of the executable.
Alternatively `type -a NAME` may reveal more, for other types of scrips, or even shadowed executables (alias "hides" the true exec).

The executable NAME for vscode seems to be `code` or `vscode`.
Settings files may be elsewhere; `apt-file find code` or possibly `vscode` may reveal these files.